# how does the data transfer inside interface callback in android

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

According to this [link](http://blog.csdn.net/u013564742/article/details/49914815), the author creates a dialog which uses interface callback to transfer data from dialog to activity.

the user defines a `DataBackListener` interface with a method `getData(String data)`,

where I lost is the user use `listener.getData(str);` to transfer the date to  `getData(String data)` method, the `data` is a parameter in the method and there is no return value, how does this work?? or which part of java should I read in order to understand it? Thanks first.

**Define a dialog with interface:**

```
/**
 * Created by mhwang on 2015/11/18.
 */
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    //callback interface
    public interface DataBackListener{
        public void getData(String data);
    }
    private EditText editText;
    private Button btnSure;

    DataBackListener listener;   //create listener
    public MyDialog(Context context, final DataBackListener listener) {
        super(context);

        //initial listener
        this.listener = listener;
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        btnSure = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sure);
        btnSure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = editText.getText().toString();

                //call the interface here to transfer the data
                listener.getData(str);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**use the dialog in an activity:**

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    EditText showResult;
    Button btnStartDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        showResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.showResult);
        btnStartDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        btnStartDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //创建对话框对象的时候对对话框进行监听
                MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(DialogActivity.this,
                        new MyDialog.DataBackListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void getData(String data) {
                                String result = data;
                                showResult.setText(result);
                            }
                        });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `listener.getData(str);`. Here the member function is called and puts the contents of `str` as data parameter.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks, I just confused that how can we use parameter in a method to transfer data, when we override the `getData(String data)` method when create the listener, is this `data` a parameter or value here?

Comment: data is a parameter and has the value of the contents/value of str.

Answer (score 0):

The result is returned inside the listener in the DialogActivity:

```
 btnStartDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //创建对话框对象的时候对对话框进行监听
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(DialogActivity.this,
                    new MyDialog.DataBackListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void getData(String data) {
                            String result = data;            <-----Here
                            showResult.setText(result);
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I know we can get the data from the listener, the question is how does the data transfer into the `getData(String data)` ?
I am confused by `listener.getData(str);` , i think this is used to call interface method and not to set the value.